# url of route goes back to default route with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

I have angular 9 application.

And I have some routes. I have a parent rout like this: http://localhost:4200/desktop

and now I have component where I want to go to: http://localhost:4200/desktop/testDesktop

but if I want to go there in the browser it goes back to: http://localhost:4200/desktop

So this is what I have:

app.component.html

```
 <app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'mobile', loadChildren: () =>
      import('../app/mobile-dashboard/mobile-dashboard.module').then(m => m.MobileDashboardModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'desktop', loadChildren: () =>
      import('./desktop-dashboard/desktop-dashboard.module').then(m => m.DesktopDashboardModule),

  },
  {
    path: 'autologin',
    component: AutoLoginComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

and

desktop.routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DesktopDashboardComponent },
  { path: 'desktop/testDesktop', component: TestDesktopComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DesktopRoutingModule {}
```

and desktop.dashboard.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DesktopDashboardComponent, BarChartComponent, TestDesktopComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    DesktopRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [TestDesktopComponent]
})
```

and desktop.dashboard.html I added this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

but so it doens't go to:

http://localhost:4200/desktop/testDesktop

So what I have to change?

Thank you

and

app.modulet.ts looks like this:

```
export function configureAuth(oidcConfigService: OidcConfigService) {
  return () =>
    oidcConfigService.withConfig({
      stsServer: 'http://localhost:4430',
      redirectUrl: window.location.origin,
      clientId: 'crowd-dashboard',
      scope: 'openid profile dashboard-api ',
      responseType: 'code',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
      unauthorizedRoute: '/unauthorized'
    });
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NavBarComponent],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatIconModule,
    DesktopDashboardModule,
    MobileDashboardModule,
    AuthModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    OidcConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: configureAuth,
      deps: [OidcConfigService],
      multi: true
    },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: try to replace `{ path: 'desktop/testDesktop', component: TestDesktopComponent }` with { path: 'testDesktop', component: TestDesktopComponent } and check if it resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for you reaction. Yes, I tried that too:  { path: 'testDesktop', component: TestDesktopComponent } but still goes back to http://localhost:4200/desktop

Comment: check your console as well. may be there is some issue with your `testDesktop`. that's why it goes back to parent component.

Comment: i just created a simple example according to your scenario and its working fine for me. checkout this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gnf4vw?file=src/app/desktop-dashboard/desktop-routing.module.ts)

Comment: but how to test it? if I do this: https://angular-ivy-gnf4vw.stackblitz.io/testDesktop nothing happens

Comment: Yes, I checked in console. But I dont see any warnings

Comment: if you just refresh the browser after navigating by click on nav-bar menu. it still go back to parent?

Comment: yes, it works, see bottom of this post. But if I do by hand it goes back to just http://localhost:4200/desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You child route must be a relative route.
The parent already indicates to go to `/desktop`.

Your child routes should be:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: DesktopDashboardComponent },
  { path: 'testDesktop', component: TestDesktopComponent }
];
```

Note that I also added a `pathMatch: 'full'` for your empty path, because otherwise other routes will be ignored.

[Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n5vy8d)

Comment: Thank you. But if I only do this: const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: DesktopDashboardComponent },
  { path: 'testDesktop', component: TestDesktopComponent }
]; it still goes back to: http://localhost:4200/desktop

Comment: Yes, I see it. It is very strange. if I do this:  <app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
 <br>
 <br>
 <a routerLink="/desktop/test-desktop">Test
<router-outlet></router-outlet> then it works if I click on the link. But if I navigate by hand to http://localhost:4200/desktop/test-desktop it doesnt work

Comment: @mightycodeNewton That is strange. Perhaps you could create a StackBlitz with your setup, so we can debug what is wrong.

Comment: I made other post for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447712/platform-blink-routing-child-routes-doesnt-work-anymore