# Platform.blink routing, child routes doesnt work anymore

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular2-routing

I have a anuglar 9 application and I am using Material. And I have two different templates: for mobile and for dekstop.

So by routing it knows witch templates has to been loaded: mobile template or desktop template.

So it looks like this:

app.component.ts

```
 constructor(
    public oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService,
    private router: Router,
    public platform: Platform,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    if (platform.BLINK === true && platform.ANDROID === true) {
      this.router.navigate(['mobile'], { relativeTo: this.route });
    } else if (platform.BLINK === true && platform.ANDROID === false) {
      this.router.navigate(['desktop'], { relativeTo: this.route });
    }
  }
```

But the problem is now that I have a router like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
    path: 'hello',
    /* pathMatch: 'full', */
    component: DesktopDashboardComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'test-desktop',
    component: TestDesktopComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DesktopRoutingModule {}
```

and my app-routing.module.ts looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
    path: 'mobile', loadChildren: () =>
      import('../app/mobile-dashboard/mobile-dashboard.module').then(m => m.MobileDashboardModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'desktop', loadChildren: () =>
      import('./desktop-dashboard/desktop-dashboard.module').then(m => m.DesktopDashboardModule),

  },
  {
    path: 'autologin',
    component: AutoLoginComponent
  }
];
```

But so if I want to navigate by hand to this url: http://localhost:4200/desktop/test-desktop it doesnt work. And it goes back to: http://localhost:4200/desktop

But if I comment this out:

```
if (platform.BLINK === true && platform.ANDROID === true) {
      this.router.navigate(['mobile'], { relativeTo: this.route });
    } else if (platform.BLINK === true && platform.ANDROID === false) {
      this.router.navigate(['desktop'], { relativeTo: this.route });
    }
```

I can go to the url:

```
http://localhost:4200/desktop/test-desktop
```

But then of course the mobile template is not working anymore. If I comment this out.

So what is the work around for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
let isMobile = false;
if (platform.iOS || platform.ANDROID) {
// mobile
  isMobile = true;
}
```